How to create a responsive master detail app using React Router?
I have prepared a simple test case at Github for my question:

In RouterLayout.jsx a media query makes the Outlet disappear at narrow screens, as you can see in the animated screenshot, where I drag the browser side to make it smaller:
RootLayout.jsx
import { Outlet } from "react-router";
import { useMediaQuery } from "@react-hook/media-query";
import MasterList from "../components/MasterList";

export default function RootLayout() {
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "flex-start",
      }}
    >
      <MasterList />
      {!isSmallScreen && (
        <div>
          <h3>Detail</h3>
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

My question please:
At small mobile phone screens only the Master List should be displayed. And when a Link is clicked there, then a Page1 or other pages should be displayed, with a possibility to return back to the Master List. This does not work yet.
At large tablet and computer screens both Master List and Page1 or others are displayed near each other. This works in my code already.
Should I add some attribute to the Links in the MasterList.jsx below?
MasterList.jsx
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MasterList = () => {
  const pages = [
    { id: 1, title: "Page 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "Page 2" },
    { id: 3, title: "Page 3" },
    { id: 4, title: "Page 4" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Master List</h2>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {pages.map((page) => (
            <li key={page.id}>
              <Link to={"/page" + page.id}>{page.title}</Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MasterList;

App.jsx
import {
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./pages/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/Page2";
import Page3 from "./pages/Page3";
import Page4 from "./pages/Page4";
import RootLayout from "./layouts/RootLayout";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
      <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
      <Route path="page3" element={<Page3 />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Page4 />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

const App = () => {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
};

export default App;


Outlets are used to render child routes, so it makes sense that the child component doesn't appear if you don't render the outlet. Can you describe more clearly what you are trying to achieve? What do you want displayed on what path on small versus big screens?

Please revise your title to ask something more specific. How to create a complex application is a very broad topic. Narrow it down to your actual issue so we don't all have to wander in here to find out what you actually need. See [ask].

On smaller view sizes where the Outlet isn't rendered the nested Route components no longer have a place to render out their element content. If I understand your post correctly you want to use RootLayout and the Outlet on the larger non-"mobile" view sizes, and on mobile view sizes render RootLayout as a sibling route instead of a parent route, so all the other routes are accessible.
Example refactor:

Create two root layouts, mobile and non-mobile.
function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "flex-start"
      }}
    >
      <MasterList />
      <div>
        <h3>Detail</h3>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileLayout() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "flex-start"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <h3>Detail</h3>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Update App to use the media query hook and conditionally render one root layout or the other, and conditionally render the MasterList as an index route on smaller screens.
export default function App() {
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");

  const router = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createBrowserRouter(
        createRoutesFromElements(
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={isSmallScreen ? <MobileLayout /> : <RootLayout />}
          >
            {isSmallScreen && <Route index element={<MasterList />} />}
            <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
            <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
            <Route path="page3" element={<Page3 />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Page4 />} />
          </Route>
        )
      ),
    [isSmallScreen]
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}



Alternative
An alternative might be to utilize the useMatch hook to test if the root "/" is the currently matched route and render MasterList. The logic is a bit more convoluted and a little less DRY. The gist here is to render the normal MasterList and Outlet on larger view sizes, and on mobile views conditionally render MasterList only if on the home page, otherwise render the Outlet for the nested routes.
Example:
import { Outlet, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function RootLayout() {
  const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery("(max-width: 768px)");
  const isHome = useMatch("/");

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: "flex-start"
      }}
    >
      {isSmallScreen ? (
        isHome ? (
          <MasterList />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3>Detail</h3>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        )
      ) : (
        <>
          <MasterList />
          <div>
            <h3>Detail</h3>
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />
      <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />
      <Route path="page3" element={<Page3 />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Page4 />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

export default function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}


I don't know what the best approach to achieve this is, but it needs to incorporate the fact that Outlet renders child routes in the Parent Component.
I would explore useMatches to see if you can use it to determine whether the Parent component was rendered on /parent or /parent/child. With that information, you could conditionally render the navigation elements:

If on /parent, always render navigation
If on /parent/child and screen is small, don't render navigation
Always render Outlet

